# ffmpeg does not compress video (produces empty file)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to compress a video with ffmpeg.

My operating system: Ubuntu 16.04

My ffmpeg version (retrieved through `ffmpeg -version`):

`ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609`

FYI, The information about the video can be retrieved with:

`ffprobe -show_streams -i "video.mp4"`

and I get:

```
ffprobe version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a2019a_video_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2019-08-28 15:28:45
  Duration: 00:03:12.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10884 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-08-28 15:28:45
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10862 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 120k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-08-28 15:28:45
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/48000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=9242624
duration=192.554667
bit_rate=12469
max_bit_rate=128000
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=9026
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:creation_time=2019-08-28 15:28:45
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=Core Media Audio
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/120000
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=32
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=left
timecode=N/A
refs=2
is_avc=1
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=60000/1001
avg_frame_rate=60000/1001
time_base=1/60000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=11549538
duration=192.492300
bit_rate=10862370
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=11538
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:creation_time=2019-08-28 15:28:45
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=Core Media Video
[/STREAM]
```

However, when I try to compress it through the following command:

`ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vcodec h264 -crf 10 output.mp4`

the process just finishes super fast without any error but I get an empty file called output.mp4 (its dimension is 0KB).

EDIT: Actually there is something which appears in the console (Even if it is not an error). The following:
`The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.`

I also tried with the following commands (changing codec etc.)

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 output.mp4`

`ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vcodec copy -crf 10 output.mp4`

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 10 output.mp4`

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 10 output.mp4`

But I have always the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had the error:

`The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.`

which was not really displayed as an error. This made me understand (also thanks to some comments) that my version of ffmpeg was really old. Before updating it I was able to compress the video by doing by adding the option `-strict -2` to my commands

However, I strongly suggest updating FFmpeg to the latest version (I followed [this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/install-ffmpeg-4-0-2-ubuntu-18-0416-04/))

I hope this post will help someone in the same trouble.

Comment: Your ffmpeg build is very old. The experimental flag for aac encoder was removed in Dec 2015.

Comment: Hey @Gyan, I tried to upgrade ffmpeg but nothing changed. I solved my problem (not able to compress the video) by adding the `-strict -2` option.

Comment: ffmpeg v 3.0 or later don't need the flag.

Comment: Would you recommend upgrading to ffmpeg version 3.0 then? (I am on Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Update to ffmpeg 4.2

Comment: Done thanks. Now I have the following

`ffmpeg version 4.1.3-0york1~16.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609`